# On git pull wait for the process that is already running in the repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository on the server. There are several Jobs that make git pull from BitBucket into that repository. Now my problem is that if several jobs will run at the same time it gives an error that the git process is already running and the job is failing. Is there a way to set a flag(I mean git pull **-[flag]** origin master) that will wait until the process finishes or at least skip git pull and don't trigger error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the pull in a script that attempts and waits for a second (or so) if there is a failure... it should eventually work, right?

```
while true; do
    if git pull blahblah; then break; fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: `if git pull …; then` does exactly that — checks exit code. The entire loop perhaps could be simplified as `while \! git pull; do sleep 1; done`. `while true` works because `true` is a program that simply does `exit 0`.

Comment: Oh, that's a good one!

Comment: But I am still getting an error: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': is at hash1 but expected hash2. I need to avoid it

Comment: @eftshift0 I added it "git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/master" before your script and the error disappeared. Thanks a lot.